# Which format is the correct format to use for mkinitcpio.conf?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, kernel, linux-kernel, mkinitcpio

I am confused about which is the proper formatting to use within mkinitcpio.conf ... I have noticed sometimes double quotes are used and other times parentheses to close off the users desired hooks, modules, etc. settings.

**Example:**

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect block filesystems"

HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
```

So which format is the right one to use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the old style:

```
HOOKS="base udev autodetect block filesystems"
```

And this is the [current new style](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio/mkinitcpio/-/blob/ca7796a27aa62bae94fe180e6f3717a0d6171101/mkinitcpio.conf#L52):

```
HOOKS=(base udev autodetect block filesystems)
```

see also [arrayize config vars in mkinitcpio.conf](https://gitlab.archlinux.org/mkinitcpio/mkinitcpio/-/commit/c5ad00c2e565eaae8e8b02b92d7f193852008c80)

This change was done in 2017, so you should see the old style only in older installs.

Both styles work so don't worry too much about it.